# Bash - How to show variable value instead of name in background process descriptions?

Tags: bash

I have a function running process like this:

```sh
hello (){
  year=2001

  longRunProcess $year
}
```

When I executed this function into background, the description of the running process is:

```sh
[1] longRunProcess $year
```

, where I missed the information of $year. It cause me some troubles when running my hello() function in a for loop, which i cannot tell which year process is still running and which is not.

Is there a way to show the $year in process as its value instead of its name?

Comment: Interesting. *Normally*, I'd punt a job control question over to [unix.se], since job control is an interactive feature that's turned off by default in scripts, and the aforementioned sister site covers user interactions with UNIX tools that are outside SO's scope is thus typically more relevant; but writing code that's sourced into an interactive shell is still writing code, so this arguably has enough of a connection to software development to be on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your approval.. I see tag Bash a lot here so opened it at SO that I'm more familiar with. To be honest with you, I don't see a necessary to split questions in different places since in the end, from a user experience, it's just a Tag difference thing..

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/ - anything in here help you?

Comment: Have you tried $1 inside longRunProcess?

Comment: Yes, $1 still be print as $1 not its value @JGFMK

Comment: Interesting. Did the @that other guy comment under the answer work for you in the end? `eval "sleep $(printf '%q' "$arg") &"`. That was a new one on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If nothing else, you could use `eval` to expand the value *before* the command is invoked, rather than during:

```
$ arg=2001
$ sleep "$arg" &
[1] 4088610
$ eval "sleep ${arg@Q} &"
[2] 4088612
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep "$arg" &
[2]+  Running                 sleep '2001' &
```

`${arg@Q}` shell escapes the variable `arg` to make sure the `eval` won't be fragile or insecure if the argument changes from a simple number to arbitrary text.

Comment: It's saying "bash - ${arg@Q} bas substitution"

Comment: I checked my bash version is 4.2.46

Comment: This is a new feature in Bash 4.4. For older versions you can use `eval "sleep $(printf '%q' "$arg") &"`

Comment: What does the `&` signify? is it the same for lines 2 & 4?

Comment: I find a more compact way doing this based on your answer: a=5;eval "sleep `echo $a` &". this works too.

Comment: @JGFMK, that & signifies that to put the process into background. Same for lines 2&4. Would you mind upvote my question once?:)

Comment: As discussed in the answer, just `$a` works for numbers but is fragile and insecure in general

Comment: @TonyYun did that too - had already favourited! ;-) Was something new I learnt about bash..

Comment: @JGFMK thanks! Yes, & is super helpful. I almost use it very everyday.